# How to get a long from a ByteBuffer (Little Endian) when you have odd number of bytes?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, nio, bitwise-operators, bytebuffer

If you have 1,2,4, or 8 bytes you just use get(), getShort(), getInt() and getLong().

Can someone help out with the logic I should use to get a long with 3,5 or 7 bytes? I probably have to paddle with zeros somehow.

Comment: Why have you got short longs? Is this how the protocol is defined?

Comment: Just get three bytes and string them together, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this problem depends on the byte order of your data.  Java's ByteBuffer class has an order(ByteOrder) method to set the endianness, but this won't help you for integer/long values of non-standard length.

Assume bb is a ByteBuffer and length is the known data length. The value variable stores the result.

This is a helper function which is used in both solutions below and is needed because Java doesn't have unsigned data types (which I find terrible):

```
private static long getUnsigned(final byte b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        return (long) b + 256;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Here is a little endian solution:

```
long value = 0;
for (int shift = 0; shift < length * 8; shift += 8) {
    value |= getUnsigned(bb.get()) << shift;
}
```

Here is a big endian solution:

```
long value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    value <<= 8;
    value |= getUnsigned(bb.get());
}
```

Comment: I had a 'brain fart' and forgot that instead of using that getUnsigned function, you could instead bitwise-and the byte by 0xFF to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast a number to another number, you sign extend the greatest value bit.  (in other words, if the highest order bit is a 1, you pad with 1's, if the highest order bit is a 0, you pad with 0's)

So in little endian, you find the highest order bit (leftmost bit in the rightmost byte), then you add a byte with either FF or 00.

Example, lets say you have a 3 byte number in little endian:

```
0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 1000 0000
```

Your highest order bit is a 1 (the 1 in the last byte), so, the sign extended result in 4 bytes is:

```
0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 1000 0000 | 1111 1111
```

Likewise, if the 3 byte number is:

```
1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 0101 1101
```

Then the 4-byte sign extended version is:

```
1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 0101 1101 | 0000 0000
```

Comment: DOn't want to ask much, but how do I turn those bytes into a long? (I guess I can just look into the Java Source code and find out by myself but if you know that from the top of your head would be helpful. THX!

Comment: no matter how many more bytes you need, the process is the same: take the highest order bit, and extend it - it is how the hardware casts between ints, shorts, bytes, and longs